# How to secure web api with OAuth 2?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

I went through each and every thread of C-SharpCorner and stack overflow on this topic but not a single one is well explained, can anyone give me a clear picture of `OAuth` and `Owin` in the context of web api security. My questions are:

1. what is meant by middleware ?
2. what is meant by `Owin` middleware?
3. How to authorize my client for specific resources with `OAuth`?
4. Is the purpose of `Owin` for self hosting in general is different than in `OAuth` implementation and in `OAuth Owin` plays different role than decoupling host and web api ?

Note:

My questions Is not about .NET CORE.